# How do you view the system logs on a Chromebook?

Tags: logging, chromebook

A Chromebook completely froze and I want to find out why.

Answer (score 5):

Go to the URL chrome://system

However, this does not include the kernel crash logs. I think they are only available in developer mode, which is a pain to switch to.